# MariaDB 10.6 Performace

Tags: mariadb

I'm migrating my database more to my surprise I had a drop in the performance search, I already checked all the indexes of the tables and they are the same

Server New
MariaDB 10.6.8
CentOS 7
8 VCpu 2.8
16 RAM

[image]

[image]

| TABLE_CATALOG | TABLE_SCHEMA | TABLE_NAME | NON_UNIQUE | INDEX_SCHEMA | INDEX_NAME | SEQ_IN_INDEX | COLUMN_NAME | COLLATION | CARDINALITY | SUB_PART | PACKED | NULLABLE | INDEX_TYPE | COMMENT | INDEX_COMMENT | IGNORED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| def | shop | nfe | 0 | shop | PRIMARY | 1 | fk_venda | A | 389502 |  |  |  | BTREE |  |  | NO |
| def | shop | nfe | 0 | shop | fk_venda | 1 | fk_venda | A | 194751 |  |  |  | BTREE |  |  | NO |
| def | shop | nfe | 1 | shop | numero | 1 | numero | A | 194751 |  |  |  | BTREE |  |  | NO |
| def | shop | vendas | 0 | shop | PRIMARY | 1 | id_venda | A | 120978 |  |  |  | BTREE |  |  | NO |
| def | shop | vendas | 0 | shop | codigo | 1 | codigo | A | 120978 |  |  | YES | BTREE |  |  | NO |
| def | shop | vendas | 0 | shop | guid | 1 | guid | A | 120978 |  |  | YES | BTREE |  |  | NO |
| def | shop | vendas | 0 | shop | erp | 1 | fk_loja | A | 2 |  |  | YES | BTREE |  |  | NO |
| def | shop | vendas | 0 | shop | erp | 2 | erp | A | 15122 |  |  | YES | BTREE |  |  | NO |
| def | shop | vendas | 1 | shop | vendas | 1 | id_venda | A | 120978 |  |  |  | BTREE |  |  | NO |
| def | shop | vendas | 1 | shop | vendas | 2 | fk_loja | A | 120978 |  |  | YES | BTREE |  |  | NO |
| def | shop | vendas | 1 | shop | vendas | 3 | fk_cliente | A | 120978 |  |  | YES | BTREE |  |  | NO |
| def | shop | vendas | 1 | shop | vendas | 4 | fk_frete | A | 120978 |  |  | YES | BTREE |  |  | NO |
| def | shop | vendas | 1 | shop | vendas | 5 | fk_status | A | 120978 |  |  | YES | BTREE |  |  | NO |
| def | shop | vendas | 1 | shop | fk_loja | 1 | fk_loja | A | 2 |  |  | YES | BTREE |  |  | NO |
| def | shop | vendas | 1 | shop | fk_cliente | 1 | fk_cliente | A | 120978 |  |  | YES | BTREE |  |  | NO |
| def | shop | vendas | 1 | shop | fk_frete | 1 | fk_frete | A | 72 |  |  | YES | BTREE |  |  | NO |
| def | shop | vendas | 1 | shop | fk_status | 1 | fk_status | A | 26 |  |  | YES | BTREE |  |  | NO |
| def | shop | vendas | 1 | shop | fk_cupom | 1 | fk_cupom | A | 2 |  |  | YES | BTREE |  |  | NO |
| def | shop | vendas | 1 | shop | fk_estado | 1 | fk_estado | A | 52 |  |  | YES | BTREE |  |  | NO |
| def | shop | vendas | 1 | shop | fk_pais | 1 | fk_pais | A | 2 |  |  | YES | BTREE |  |  | NO |
| def | shop | vendas | 1 | shop | fk_pagamento | 1 | fk_pagamento | A | 38 |  |  | YES | BTREE |  |  | NO |
| def | shop | vendas | 1 | shop | phpsessid | 1 | phpsessid | A | 120978 |  |  | YES | BTREE |  |  | NO |
| def | shop | vendas | 1 | shop | notificar | 1 | notificar | A | 4 |  |  | YES | BTREE |  |  | NO |
| def | shop | vendas | 1 | shop | vendas_ibfk_9 | 1 | fk_marketplace | A | 48 |  |  | YES | BTREE |  |  | NO |
| def | shop | vendas | 1 | shop | data_compra | 1 | data_compra | A | 120978 |  |  | YES | BTREE |  |  | NO |
| def | shop | vendas | 1 | shop | tags | 1 | tags | A | 8 |  |  | YES | BTREE |  |  | NO |
| def | shop | vendas | 1 | shop | coupon_id | 1 | coupon_id | A | 32 |  |  | YES | BTREE |  |  | NO |
| def | shop | vendas | 1 | shop | created_at | 1 | created_at | A | 120978 |  |  |  | BTREE |  |  | NO |

```
CREATE TABLE `vendas` (
  `guid` varchar(40) DEFAULT uuid(),
  `id_venda` int(11) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `codigo` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `erp` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_loja` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_cliente` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_frete` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_cupom` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipment_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phpsessid` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subtotal` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT 0.00,
  `desconto` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT 0.00,
  `abatimento` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT 0.00,
  `desconto_boleto` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT 0.0000,
  `desconto_boleto_rede` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT 0.0000,
  `desconto_cartao` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT 0.0000,
  `acrescimo` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT 0.00,
  `tarifa` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT 0.00,
  `juros` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT 0.00,
  `data_compra` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `data_pagamento` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `data_preparo` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `data_envio` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `data_estimada` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_entrega` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `data_cancelamento` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `numero_objeto` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
  `comentario` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `tipo_residencia` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `endereco` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `numero` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bairro` varchar(50) DEFAULT '',
  `complemento` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
  `cidade` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_estado` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_pais` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `provincia` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `referencia` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `entregar_para` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cep` char(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_pagamento` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `parcelas` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fone1` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fone2` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cpf_cnpj` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prazo` int(2) DEFAULT 0,
  `ultima_alteracao` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `integrada` int(1) DEFAULT 0,
  `notificar` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `host` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_marketplace` int(11) DEFAULT 1,
  `dynamic_cols` blob DEFAULT NULL,
  `tags` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `whatsapp` int(1) DEFAULT 0,
  `coupon_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_venda`),
  UNIQUE KEY `codigo` (`codigo`) USING BTREE,
  UNIQUE KEY `guid` (`guid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `erp` (`fk_loja`,`erp`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `vendas` (`id_venda`,`fk_loja`,`fk_cliente`,`fk_frete`,`fk_status`),
  KEY `fk_loja` (`fk_loja`),
  KEY `fk_cliente` (`fk_cliente`),
  KEY `fk_frete` (`fk_frete`),
  KEY `fk_status` (`fk_status`),
  KEY `fk_cupom` (`fk_cupom`),
  KEY `fk_estado` (`fk_estado`),
  KEY `fk_pais` (`fk_pais`),
  KEY `fk_pagamento` (`fk_pagamento`),
  KEY `phpsessid` (`phpsessid`),
  KEY `notificar` (`notificar`),
  KEY `vendas_ibfk_9` (`fk_marketplace`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `data_compra` (`data_compra`),
  KEY `tags` (`tags`),
  KEY `coupon_id` (`coupon_id`),
  KEY `created_at` (`created_at`),
  CONSTRAINT `vendas_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_loja`) REFERENCES `lojas` (`id_loja`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `vendas_ibfk_10` FOREIGN KEY (`coupon_id`) REFERENCES `discount_coupon` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `vendas_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_cliente`) REFERENCES `clientes` (`id_cliente`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `vendas_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_frete`) REFERENCES `fretes` (`id_frete`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `vendas_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_status`) REFERENCES `status` (`id_status`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `vendas_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_cupom`) REFERENCES `cupom` (`id_cupom`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `vendas_ibfk_6` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_estado`) REFERENCES `estados` (`id_estado`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `vendas_ibfk_7` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_pais`) REFERENCES `paises` (`id_pais`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `vendas_ibfk_8` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_pagamento`) REFERENCES `pagamentos` (`id_pagamento`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `vendas_ibfk_9` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_marketplace`) REFERENCES `marketplace` (`id_marketplace`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=693460 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;

CREATE TABLE `nfe` (
  `fk_venda` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `numero` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `serie` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `chave` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `emissao` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  `xml` longtext DEFAULT NULL,
  `arquivo` blob DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`fk_venda`),
  UNIQUE KEY `fk_venda` (`fk_venda`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `numero` (`numero`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Server Old
MariaDB 10.5.16
CentOS 7
8 VCpu 2.2
16 RAM

```
CREATE TABLE `vendas` (
  `guid` varchar(40) DEFAULT uuid(),
  `id_venda` int(11) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `codigo` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `erp` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_loja` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_cliente` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_frete` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_cupom` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipment_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phpsessid` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subtotal` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT 0.00,
  `desconto` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT 0.00,
  `abatimento` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT 0.00,
  `desconto_boleto` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT 0.0000,
  `desconto_boleto_rede` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT 0.0000,
  `desconto_cartao` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT 0.0000,
  `acrescimo` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT 0.00,
  `tarifa` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT 0.00,
  `juros` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT 0.00,
  `data_compra` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `data_pagamento` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `data_preparo` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `data_envio` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `data_estimada` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_entrega` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `data_cancelamento` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `numero_objeto` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
  `comentario` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `tipo_residencia` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `endereco` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `numero` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bairro` varchar(50) DEFAULT '',
  `complemento` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
  `cidade` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_estado` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_pais` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `provincia` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `referencia` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `entregar_para` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cep` char(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_pagamento` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `parcelas` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fone1` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fone2` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cpf_cnpj` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prazo` int(2) DEFAULT 0,
  `ultima_alteracao` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `integrada` int(1) DEFAULT 0,
  `notificar` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `host` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_marketplace` int(11) DEFAULT 1,
  `dynamic_cols` blob DEFAULT NULL,
  `tags` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `whatsapp` int(1) DEFAULT 0,
  `coupon_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_venda`),
  UNIQUE KEY `codigo` (`codigo`) USING BTREE,
  UNIQUE KEY `guid` (`guid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `erp` (`fk_loja`,`erp`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `vendas` (`id_venda`,`fk_loja`,`fk_cliente`,`fk_frete`,`fk_status`),
  KEY `fk_cliente` (`fk_cliente`),
  KEY `fk_frete` (`fk_frete`),
  KEY `fk_status` (`fk_status`),
  KEY `fk_cupom` (`fk_cupom`),
  KEY `fk_estado` (`fk_estado`),
  KEY `fk_pais` (`fk_pais`),
  KEY `fk_pagamento` (`fk_pagamento`),
  KEY `phpsessid` (`phpsessid`),
  KEY `notificar` (`notificar`),
  KEY `vendas_ibfk_9` (`fk_marketplace`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `tags` (`tags`),
  KEY `coupon_id` (`coupon_id`),
  KEY `created_at` (`created_at`),
  KEY `data_compra` (`data_compra`),
  CONSTRAINT `vendas_ibfk_10` FOREIGN KEY (`coupon_id`) REFERENCES `discount_coupon` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `vendas_ibfk_11` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_loja`) REFERENCES `lojas` (`id_loja`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `vendas_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_cliente`) REFERENCES `clientes` (`id_cliente`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `vendas_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_frete`) REFERENCES `fretes` (`id_frete`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `vendas_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_status`) REFERENCES `status` (`id_status`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `vendas_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_cupom`) REFERENCES `cupom` (`id_cupom`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `vendas_ibfk_6` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_estado`) REFERENCES `estados` (`id_estado`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `vendas_ibfk_7` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_pais`) REFERENCES `paises` (`id_pais`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `vendas_ibfk_8` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_pagamento`) REFERENCES `pagamentos` (`id_pagamento`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `vendas_ibfk_9` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_marketplace`) REFERENCES `marketplace` (`id_marketplace`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=693701 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;

CREATE TABLE `nfe` (
  `fk_venda` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `numero` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `serie` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `chave` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `emissao` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  `xml` longtext DEFAULT NULL,
  `arquivo` blob DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`fk_venda`),
  UNIQUE KEY `fk_venda` (`fk_venda`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `numero` (`numero`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

[image]
[image]

| TABLE_CATALOG | TABLE_SCHEMA | TABLE_NAME | NON_UNIQUE | INDEX_SCHEMA | INDEX_NAME | SEQ_IN_INDEX | COLUMN_NAME | COLLATION | CARDINALITY | SUB_PART | PACKED | NULLABLE | INDEX_TYPE | COMMENT | INDEX_COMMENT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| def | shop | vendas | 0 | shop | PRIMARY | 1 | id_venda | A | 120554 |  |  |  | BTREE |  |  |
| def | shop | vendas | 0 | shop | codigo | 1 | codigo | A | 120554 |  |  | YES | BTREE |  |  |
| def | shop | vendas | 0 | shop | guid | 1 | guid | A | 120554 |  |  | YES | BTREE |  |  |
| def | shop | vendas | 0 | shop | erp | 1 | fk_loja | A | 2 |  |  | YES | BTREE |  |  |
| def | shop | vendas | 0 | shop | erp | 2 | erp | A | 17222 |  |  | YES | BTREE |  |  |
| def | shop | vendas | 1 | shop | vendas | 1 | id_venda | A | 120554 |  |  |  | BTREE |  |  |
| def | shop | vendas | 1 | shop | vendas | 2 | fk_loja | A | 120554 |  |  | YES | BTREE |  |  |
| def | shop | vendas | 1 | shop | vendas | 3 | fk_cliente | A | 120554 |  |  | YES | BTREE |  |  |
| def | shop | vendas | 1 | shop | vendas | 4 | fk_frete | A | 120554 |  |  | YES | BTREE |  |  |
| def | shop | vendas | 1 | shop | vendas | 5 | fk_status | A | 120554 |  |  | YES | BTREE |  |  |
| def | shop | vendas | 1 | shop | fk_cliente | 1 | fk_cliente | A | 120554 |  |  | YES | BTREE |  |  |
| def | shop | vendas | 1 | shop | fk_frete | 1 | fk_frete | A | 74 |  |  | YES | BTREE |  |  |
| def | shop | vendas | 1 | shop | fk_status | 1 | fk_status | A | 24 |  |  | YES | BTREE |  |  |
| def | shop | vendas | 1 | shop | fk_cupom | 1 | fk_cupom | A | 2 |  |  | YES | BTREE |  |  |
| def | shop | vendas | 1 | shop | fk_estado | 1 | fk_estado | A | 52 |  |  | YES | BTREE |  |  |
| def | shop | vendas | 1 | shop | fk_pais | 1 | fk_pais | A | 2 |  |  | YES | BTREE |  |  |
| def | shop | vendas | 1 | shop | fk_pagamento | 1 | fk_pagamento | A | 36 |  |  | YES | BTREE |  |  |
| def | shop | vendas | 1 | shop | phpsessid | 1 | phpsessid | A | 120554 |  |  | YES | BTREE |  |  |
| def | shop | vendas | 1 | shop | notificar | 1 | notificar | A | 4 |  |  | YES | BTREE |  |  |
| def | shop | vendas | 1 | shop | vendas_ibfk_9 | 1 | fk_marketplace | A | 50 |  |  | YES | BTREE |  |  |
| def | shop | vendas | 1 | shop | tags | 1 | tags | A | 8 |  |  | YES | BTREE |  |  |
| def | shop | vendas | 1 | shop | coupon_id | 1 | coupon_id | A | 30 |  |  | YES | BTREE |  |  |
| def | shop | vendas | 1 | shop | created_at | 1 | created_at | A | 120554 |  |  |  | BTREE |  |  |
| def | shop | vendas | 1 | shop | data_compra | 1 | data_compra | A | 120554 |  |  | YES | BTREE |  |  |
| def | shop | nfe | 0 | shop | PRIMARY | 1 | fk_venda | A | 196585 |  |  |  | BTREE |  |  |
| def | shop | nfe | 0 | shop | fk_venda | 1 | fk_venda | A | 196585 |  |  |  | BTREE |  |  |
| def | shop | nfe | 1 | shop | numero | 1 | numero | A | 196585 |  |  |  | BTREE |  |  |

Answer (score 2):

Three possibilities that I can think of:

- `vendas`: Replace `INDEX(fk_loga)` with `INDEX(fk_loja, codigo)`.  I would expect a better EXPLAIN.
- I assume that `status` has `PRIMARY KEY(status)`.  The `JOIN` to `status` seems to be useless.  Will you get the same answer if you remove it?  That will also speed up the query.
- `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "query_cache%";` on each server.  There may have been a change there.

Comment: the first suggestion does not take effect, the second suggestion to remove the join, I would have the same answer, I need them, in this case I left the sql simpler just to exemplify that the join in the tables is screwing with the query, other joins what I do with this table is slow on this new server  

equal values on both servers  
query_cache_limit=1048576  
query_cache_min_res_unit=4096  
query_cache_size=1048576  
query_cache_strip_comments=OFF  
query_cache_type=OFF  
query_cache_wlock_invalidate=OFF

Comment: @ElvisReis - Please show us the full query, there may be subtle things lost in the simplification.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
[image]

after adding an index to the status.tag
[image]
[image]

it makes no sense for me to exceed my index bank in this case the status table is small with less than 30 records